# Windows Phone - Store image in database or IsoStore

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

I capture images within my app and need to store them. I'm not sure where the right place is to store the captured image. Storing the image as byte array in the database would be very nice but whats happening if the next-gen smartphones getting a high-resoltion camera and the images become bigger? Are they exceeding my database limit or my app becomes slowly?

Is it better to store the image into IsoStore?

Answer (score 1):

I'd store in the isostore, if you want to use database, you might just store the path of the image or name to be able to find it from the isostore.

It should be faster to use isostore instead of database.

Comment: This is my current solution. I would prefer to store it in the database because I need only one byte array property, and can use this for binding to view and serialization. If the IsoStore is really faster, then I would change my opinion instantly but I need evidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store image in database use [blob](/questions/tagged/blob) type attribute in database,
Convert the image in [byte-array](/questions/tagged/byte-array) and execute the database command.
To convert the object in byte array follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803215/how-to-convert-any-type-of-object-into-byte-array-in-windows-phone-8).

This answer is based on [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) database.

Comment: I'm using the built-in SQLCe database.