# Convert/Serialize Dictionary<string,string> to byte array byte[] in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, serialization, dictionary, arrays

I am developing applications for windows phone 8. I have dictionary of the format Dictionary. I want to convert this dictionary to byte array. According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972607/convert-dictionary-or-list-to-byte) dictionary can be serialized into byte array using the BinaryFormtter class. However according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376765/how-to-use-binaryformatter-in-windows-phone-7) I cannot use BinaryFormatter in windows phone 8. Is there any workaround method available so that I serialize my Dictionary?

Comment: Well what format do you want it to be in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803215/how-to-convert-any-type-of-object-into-byte-array-in-windows-phone-8 See if this helps.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want the dictionary to be in format of byte array[]. I am sorry. I didnt your question exactly

Comment: That's like saying you want to save an image as bytes - I'm asking the equivalent of jpg, PNG, gif etc but for your dictionary.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to use this byte array to pass it to sha 256 algorithm to encode. So i guess i want the bytes to be utf-8 encoded. I hope it answers the question.

Comment: @hcnimkar: Are you *just* trying to take a hash for the dictionary? If that's all you need, then you can invent your own format, so long as you control everywhere that's going to do it. But fundamentally a dictionary isn't just a string, so it doesn't make sense to just talk about it being UTF-8-encoded. You could serialize it to JSON and then UTF-8-encode *that*, for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
byte[] content = UTF8.GetBytes(UrlEncode(body));
```